# Windows phone 8: Load multiple local HTMLs from one page by passing values

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

I am new to Windows 8 phone dev. I am trying to achieve this android code in Windows Phone 8.1:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.some_layout);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String value = "file:///android_asset/default_page.html";
    if(extras !=null) {
       value = extras.getString("keyHTML");
    }
    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.loadUrl(value);
}
```

Such that I can pass parameters and change HTMLs like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, WebViewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("keyHTML","file:///android_asset/page_button_1.html");
startActivity(i);
```

I have several HTMLs to load and would want a better way to achieve this.

Comment: Are you just asking how to load HTML into a WebBrowser control via parameters from a page Navigation?

Comment: Yes, something like that... But because the HTMLs are many, I wouldnt want to create a page for each HTML page loaded. In android, You first create a page where you add a webview control, and then in the second page, you navigate to the first page and access the webview control, then instead of loading the default URL I can change the URL from the second page. I dont know if you get me.